# troubles with jQuery mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

I am trying to create a menu with this structure:

```
<ul id="primary" class="menuOptions">
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2
         <div id="secondary">
            <ul class="menuOptions">
               <li>subItemOne</li>
               <li>subItemTwo</li>
           </ul>
         </div>
     </li>
     <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I am animating it with this script:

```
$j('.menuOptions li').each(function(i){
//applies to all menu options
    $j(this)
   .bind('mouseover',function() {
          $j(this).toggleClass("over");
       })
       .bind('mouseleave',function() {
          $j(this).toggleClass("over");
       });                  
  });
```

I am finding that the toggleClass function is being called on the primary menu item as the mouse moves over the secondary menu items.  I know that mouseleave is not supposed to be called until the mouse is off the children as well, so I am confused.

Do I need to actively stop event propagation somehow?

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try with just using the hover function.

```
$j('ul.menuOptions li').hover(function(){
          $j(this).toggleClass("over");
       } ,
       function() {
          $j(this).toggleClass("over");
       }
);
```

Comment: The behavior is different but still not as desired.  With my version, the primary item flashes as I move over each secondary.  With your version, the primary toggles just once as the mouse leaves the primary area and moves onto the secondary area.  So yours looks better, but still not what I want.

Comment: Whoops!  My mistake, I was testing on a bad example.  Your solution does work.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saved me a lot of time! Much better than tracking mousemove events or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem was that you were coupling *mouse**over*** with *mouse**leave***.

See http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

In general, the couplings you want are:

- *mouse**enter*** with *mouse**leave***
- *mouse**over*** with *mouse**out***.

Using other combinations can result in undesired behavior. 
*mouse**over*** and *mouse**out*** are older events which, while still occasionally useful, are generally inferior to *mouse**enter*** and *mouse**leave***.

You can also try to simply things by using
***hover***, is exactly equivalent to using *mouse**enter*** and *mouse**leave***.